# Buying button sending to an empty cart page instead of product page

Tags: magento-1.9

When I have all the caches active the buying product button at the home page sends the client to an empty cart page, and when I disable all the caches the buttons start to behave normally.
Any help is much appreciated, magento CE 1.9.0.1
All the best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the URL of your website and also what is the setting in admin-> system -> configuration-> sales -> Checkout-> Shopping Basket -> After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart (Yes or no)?

Cheers
S

Comment: Thank you so much for the lead, the After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart (Yes or no)? was with yes.

Comment: Did it solve the problem?

Comment: Thank you so much for the lead, the After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart (Yes or no)? was with yes. As soon I changed to NO the behavior got much better since now it shows a message saying that the product was added to the cart. Anyways is much better!! Thank you again. KUDOS

Comment: Yes it dit, all the best!

Comment: Glad I could help!